# What is the maximum gap that water won't pass through for hydrophobic surfaces?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

If I had 2 hydrophobic surfaces (in this particular case, 2 sheets of coated glass), placed edge-to-edge, what is the maximum gap between the sheets where water would not drip between the sheets? Is there a relation between contact angle (i.e. how hydrophobic the glass is), and gap distance? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Very nice picture - did you draw it yourself or did you copy it from somewhere? In the latter case we request that you give attribution.

Comment: The answer is going to depend on the size of the drop. A drop that is smaller than the gap can always "squeeze through". Can you please clarify what you are really asking?

Comment: Thank you, I drew it myself (Sketchup). As for the drop size, let's assume it's larger than the gap. The real-life case is 2 sheets of glass that are butted together but need to keep water from getting between them. The edges of the glass sheets will be cut straight and polished smooth, but "smooth" isn't never perfectly smooth, and "straight" is never straight, so I'm wondering how much gap would be acceptable due to irregularities in the edge. The drop actually isn't even necessarily a drop shape, but rather water on the surface. I just assumes it would form drops because it's hydrophobic.

Comment: I thought I recognized the style. Well done. The answer to your question is going to depend on the drop size, surface tension, and hydrophobicity. Do you need the exact equations, the general approach, or the solution to a more narrowly defined problem?

Comment: A general approach would be appreciated, but if you can provide an exact equation that would be even better!